# could be recording video & OS timestamp with ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, timestamp

I'm newbie of Video, Image processing.

I want to recording High resolution & frame video with FFmpeg. (1920 * 1080 * 60FPS)
and, I need to Timestamp data of OS(Windows or ubuntu) for each frames.
I hope to Timestamp data is formatted with text data.

I searched any of using FFmpeg, but I couldn't find recording video with timestamp data.

Is there any idea of recording video & timestamp data with ffmpeg?

Or, could you notice me with simple tip of making solution with ffmpeg ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "write/find code for me"-site. What have you implemented so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What format is ffmpeg to output?